# eslint import/unresolved issue in Expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, eslint, storybook

I have an `import/unresolved` problem in eslint configuration.

- index.js

```
import PropertyIcon from './property' 
// Unable to resolve path to module './property'
// eslint(import/no-unresolved)
...
```

I have 2 files for web and native icons, so their file names are `property.web.js` and `property.native.js`

How can I solve this eslint problem?